# Is there an established deployment process for Kubernetes and AWS for Windows developers?

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, kubernetes

nb. I mean Linux nodes and containers, but where one's development environment is Windows.

As far as I can see, there are two main tools for making Kubernetes deployments to AWS:

- kops
- kube-aws

However, both of these tools are Linux/MacOS only. The binaries can be used using Windows Subsystem for Linux, but unfortunately, I believe they're subject to [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/330).

Given how popular Kubernetes and AWS is - I would have imagined that there's quite a few developers using Windows making deployments to AWS - I'm wondering how they're doing it.

Comment: Linux VM? I can't imagine trying to develop for Kubernetes on Windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Looking at [Terraform](https://terraform.io) combined with [Typhoon](https://typhoon.psdn.io/). Terraform is cross-platform infrastructure provisioning tool, that support modules for common functions. Typhoon is such a module and IMHO the most reliable approach to deploying cluster.

I have been evaluating deployment Tools for weeks and specialized Tools like kops had a very high failure rate in producing a running cluster. Typhoon on the other Hand works and combined with Terraform you can basically store the definitions of your cluster in Version Control too.